# TTStyledTextLabel opening a URL [Open]

Tags: iphone, ios, three20, ttstyledtextlabel

I am trying to open url using TTStyledTextLabel. I searched but found that I have to append `<a href=''></a>` this in my string.

Tried but it still not working.

```
    TTStyledTextLabel *tnc = ....;
    NSString *message = @"My message";

    message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<a href=''></a> %@ http://www.google.co.in", message];
    TTStyledText *text = [TTStyledText textFromXHTML:message lineBreaks:YES URLs:YES];

    tnc.text = text;
```

Am I doing this in correct way. Whenever I tap on url it gets highligted but makes my other string invisible. Should I have to use a webView to open a url or it will directly open a safari?

Answer (score 0):

You message string is not correct.May be it's the following:

```
message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<a href='http://www.google.co.in'>%@</a>", message];
```

When you tap the message,it will open a url in a webView.